# joomla add view into another view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, joomla, joomla1.7

Im using joomla MVC and I want to build a form that has different tabs which are different sections of the form with inputs in it. There are some tabs that are common to other forms that I need to include.

I would like to be able to load this common content from a separate file or view so i dont have duplicate code, plus is easier when I need to do a change to the form so I dont have to do it in all the forms. It's like displaying a view inside another view.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Joomla! provides the `loadTemplate` method to views.

So if you're currently in a `tmpl` file loaded for layout `edit` (ie. `tmpl/edit.php` ) you can call `$this->loadTemplate('tab1');` and Joomla! will load the `tmpl/edit_tab1.php` file in the same view as your `edit.php`.

In that same view if you wanted to include say `tmpl/other_tab1.php` you would have to temporarily set the layout to **other**, eg. in one of our components during the *Run* template we need a tab from the *Edit* template, so we use:

```
<?php $this->setLayout('edit'); // This is ugly
      echo $this->loadTemplate('plan');
      $this->setLayout('run'); ?>
```

To load a template from another view alltogether, I think you would have to temporarily over-ride the `view` value, load the template then restore the view. eg.

```
$jinput =  JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jinput->set('view', 'other');
$this->loadTemplate('tab2');
$jinput->set('view', 'original');
```

*NB: this last bit I haven't had time to test but it should work.*

Comment: Thanks cppl, this was the aswer i was looking for!

Comment: it works with brother views with in the tmpl, but it doesn't work between different views

Comment: don't forget the ECHO $this->loadTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can load a different template file for a different view manually, by simply requiring it. The following is for a view called "nameofotherview" with the layout "layoutname". If this is for an admin view use `JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINSTRATOR` instead.

```
require(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE . '/views/nameofotherview/tmpl/layoutname.php');
```

Remember that the data set up in the view class needs to be compatible with the main layout as well as the layout you're loading from elsewhere.

A side effect of doing this is that template overrides won't work. The loadTemplate function is doing a require but it checks the template paths for overrides first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vews in other views as described in Joomla documentation: [Sharing layouts across views or extensions with JLayout](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout)